# how to stop a starting windows service?

Tags: windows, service

Is there a way to stop a windows service that its status is "Starting"?

I'm working on Windows 7/Server 2008 and the service is running under an admin user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Taskkill

for example to kill the w32Time service

```
 Taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES EQ W32Time"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try right clicking on it from the Services tab in Task Manager.  If there is the option to "Go To Process" (note that you should "Show Processes from All Users" on the Processes tab beforehand) then ending the highlighted process may stop it if all else has failed.